# Kernel panic not syncing timeout synchronizing machine check over cpus

Tags: server, kernel, raid, sync

We installed an Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS to one of our customer's server. Server has large storage drives and software RAIDed SSD disks for OS.

Server is crashing randomly. And we are getting error message of:

> Kernel panic not syncing: Timeout synchronizing machine check over CPUs

[image: kernel panic image]

I suspect that machine has a bad hard drive or memory. But customer insists that machine is healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that error indicates that a fatal machine check exception occurred and a timeout occurred while waiting for all the CPUs to become synchronized.  While it is hard to say what kind of machine check exception (MCE) occurred from this error message, normally it indicates some fatal hardware error (for example memory <-> CPU or mother board related).

Comment: …or other faulty on-board chips or devices like storage controllers. Try to unplug and disable (in BIOS) everything but the bare necessities to boot Ubuntu from USB to see what happens.